# Google Play Store: App page does not show total Installation on Additional Information

Tags: android

I have developed few apps, and published them on google playstore, but it is not showing number of installs to user and it's show on Google play console total install by user is more than 60 but not show on google playstore.

What's wrong in that, can you help me in that?
Look at this screenshot to understand my problem,there is no additional information shown for number of installs

My apps can be seen here.   [Place Finder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googleplaceapitest&hl=en)[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have patience, it takes 2-3 days to show the number some time. So just wait, No action is needed from your side :)